# Transfer Learning Tensorflow.js size/shape error

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I am trying to apply transfer learning by using a knnClassifier and the mobileNet image recognition model in Tensorflow.js I am, however, receiving the following error:

*Size(28672) must match the product of shape 28,3072*

I don't know how to tackle this issue, I've tried creating tensor3D, resizing using bilinear and nearest neighbor but to no avail. I was wondering if someone here could check this out.

Note that my idea here is to train images from certain folders and assign them to their class using the add example of the knnClassifier. I have a function that reads the image from a path, and an async function that trains the model and makes a prediction from an image.

................................................................................................

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
//MobileNet : pre-trained model for TensorFlow.js
const mobilenet = require('@tensorflow-models/mobilenet');
//The module provides native TensorFlow execution
//in backend JavaScript applications under the Node.js runtime.
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const knnClassifier = require('./node_modules/@tensorflow-models/knn-classifier/dist/knn-classifier');

var glob = require('glob')
//The fs module provides an API for interacting with the file system.
const fs = require('fs');

const readImage = path => {
  //reads the entire contents of a file.
  //readFileSync() is synchronous and blocks execution until finished.
  const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
  //Given the encoded bytes of an image,
  //it returns a 3D or 4D tensor of the decoded image. Supports BMP, GIF, JPEG and PNG formats.
  var tfimage = tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);

  // const t3d = tf.tensor3d(Array.from(tfimage.dataSync()),[tfimage.shape[0], tfimage.shape[1], 1])
  const smalImg = tf.image.resizeNearestNeighbor(tfimage, [32, 32]);
  const resized = tf.cast(smalImg, 'float32');

  // t3d.reshape([32,32,3])
  // var smalImg = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tfimage, [368, 432]);
  // const resized = tf.cast(smalImg, 'float32');
  return resized;
}


var mainDirectory = "./img_samples/";

const imageClassification = async path => {
  const classifier = await knnClassifier.create();

  const image = await readImage(path);
  // Load the model.
  const model = await mobilenet.load();
  // Classify the image.
  const predictions = await model.classify(image);
  // print results on terminal
  console.log('Classification Results:', predictions);

  var folders = fs.readdirSync(mainDirectory);

  var filesPerClass = [];
  for(var i=0;i<folders.length;i++){
    files = fs.readdirSync(mainDirectory+folders[i]);
    var files_complete = [];
    for(var j=0;j<files.length;j++){
      files_complete.push(mainDirectory+folders[i]+"/"+files[j]);
    }
    filesPerClass.push(files_complete);
  }

  for(var i=0;i<filesPerClass.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<filesPerClass[i].length;j++){
      imageSample = readImage(filesPerClass[i][j]);
      console.log(imageSample);
      activation = await model.infer(imageSample, 'conv_preds');  //main directory
      classifier.addExample(activation,i);
    }
  }

  console.log(readImage('./hospitalTest.jpg'))
  const predictionsTest = await classifier.predictClass(readImage('./hospitalTest.jpg'));   
  console.log('classficationTest:',predictionsTest);
}

if (process.argv.length !== 3) throw new Error('Incorrect arguments: node classify.js <IMAGE_FILE>');

imageClassification(process.argv[2]);
```

Comment: What part of your code is throwing the error ?

Comment: @edkeveked Hello, it's when I try to make the prediction, if I remove the predictClass part of the code it doesn't throw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the knn classifier is trained using an output from a node of mobilenet, the prediction needs to be done likewise

```
outputMobilenet = await model.infer(readImage('./hospitalTest.jpg'), 'conv_preds')
predicted = await classifier.predictClass(outputMobilenet)
```

Comment: Yes! This worked Thank you!!
edit: much luv and fluff